# Regex to Strip Special Characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to use regex.replace to strip out unwanted characters, but I need to account for spaces:

```
string asdf = "doésn't work?";
string regie = @"([{}\(\)\^$&._%#!@=<>:;,~`'\’ \*\?\/\+\|\[\\\\]|\]|\-)";
Response.Write(Regex.Replace(asdf,regie,"").Replace(" ","-"));
```

returns doésntwork instead of doésnt-work

Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This could have saved you the embarrassment: http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regular expression includes a space, so the space gets stripped out before the `string.Replace` is called.

```
string regie = @"([{}\(\)\^$&._%#!@=<>:;,~`'\’ \*\?\/\+\|\[\\\\]|\]|\-)";
                                              ^ here
```

Remove it from the regular expression and your code should do what you expect:

```
string regie = @"([{}\(\)\^$&._%#!@=<>:;,~`'\’\*\?\/\+\|\[\\\\]|\]|\-)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a space inside your regex, right here: `\’ \*`.