# Why is ColdFusion throwing errors on regex to strip special characters?

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm using `reReplace` to strip special characters from filenames.  The following regex throws exceptions (see below) in my code.  However, when I test the regex string in a [ColdFusion Regex Utility](http://www.bennadel.com/resources/demo/regular_expression_replace/index.cfm) it works just fine.

Here is my code:

```
reReplace(tmpName,"[{}\(\)\^$&%#!@=<>:;,~`'\'\*\?\/\+\|\[\\\\]|\]|\-",'','all')
```

And the error:

> Error Messages: Invalid token @ found on line 29 at column 45.
>
> The CFML compiler was processing:
>
> ```
> An expression beginning with !, on line 29, column 44.This message is usually caused by a problem in the expressions structure.
> ```

If I escape the `@` symbol with `\@` I get this error:

> Error Type: Template : [N/A] Error Messages: Invalid CFML construct
>   found on line 29 at column 45. ColdFusion was looking at the following
>   text:
>
> \\
>   The CFML compiler was processing:
>
> ```
> An expression beginning with !, on line 29, column 44.This message is usually caused by a problem in the expressions structure.
> ```

My original source for this regex string is: [Regex to Strip Special Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733144/regex-to-strip-special-characters)

I removed the `.` and `_` as these characters should be allowed.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the `!` instead?

Comment: Just tried that. Now I get: `An expression beginning with \", on line 29, column 30.This message is usually caused by a problem in the expressions structure.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you have an unescaped `#` in the middle of the regex.

Bear in mind that `#` has special meaning in CFML, so if you want to use a literal `#`, you need to escape it as `##`.

So your regex should be:

```
[{}\(\)\^$&%##!@=<>:;,~`'\'\*\?\/\+\|\[\\\\]|\]|\-
```

Comment: omg. I now have a palm shaped indentation in my forehead. Thanks!

Comment: There are a *lot* of incorrectly escaped characters in that expression. I urge you to make a second, careful pass to escape *only* what's needed, which is: 

^ $ * . + ? ( ) [ ] { } \ |

Comment: Many of those characters don't need escaping - here's a simpler version: `[{}()^$&%##!@=<>:;,~\`'*?/+|\[\]\-\\]` - the only characters needing to be prefixed with backslashes are `[` `]` `-` `\\`  (The `^` would need it if it was first, but doesn't need it if not first).

Comment: Heh, just seen Shawn's comment now, but it is _incorrect_ - to re-iterate: there are only **five** characters that may need prefixing with a backslash here: `[^[]-\]` => `[\^\[\]\-\\]` - nothing else needs to be escaped when used inside a character class.